# Open the menu without increase the size of the navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navigation bar with items and menus, done with flexbox, the problem that when opening the menu the navbar expands, could it be avoided? I've tried other paths using absolute position with respect to navbar, but the problem that by decreasing the size of the screen the position is uncertain. Would it be possible to expand the menu without increasing the size of the navbar?

```css
.menu {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.menu ul li {
  width: 20%;
}
.menu ul li > ul {
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 21px;
  background: blue;
}
.menu ul li > ul li {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu .sub-menu li > a {
  color: black;
}
.menu .sub-menu > a:after {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">Games</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">manga/hq</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">action figure</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">raridades</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">Filmes</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear, please re check your question, fix spelling mistakes and reword it so that it is somewhat understandable! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: relative` on `.menu ul li:hover > ul` is the problem - removing it solves it almost. Now add `position: relative` to `menu ul li` and `right: 0` to `.menu ul li:hover > ul`. See demo below:

```css
.menu {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.menu ul li {
  width: 20%;
  position: relative; /* added */
}
.menu ul li > ul {
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 21px;
  background: blue;
}
.menu ul li > ul li {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  /*position: relative;*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0; /* added */
}
.menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu .sub-menu li > a {
  color: black;
}
.menu .sub-menu > a:after {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">Games</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">manga/hq</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">action figure</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">raridades</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/games">Filmes</a>                    
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usados</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="#">Raros</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Secção Nostalgia</a></li>   
          </ul>                  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```